# Jquery click event not fire in last child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html code

```
<table id='code'>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td class='action'>data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td class='action'>data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td class='action'>data4</td>
    </tr>
```

jquery code is.

```
$('#code tr td').on('click',function(){
alert($(this).html());
});
```

this is my jquery code this is working. this fire click event on all td tags.

but I want click event fire only first three `td` not in `td.action` means last `td`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to ignore a set of elements matching the selector

```
$('#code tr td:not(.action)').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/82XG6/)

or

```
$('#code tr td').not('.action').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Erupx/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#code tr').on("click","td:not('.action')",function(){
alert($(this).html());
});
```